# using for loop for floating number and uneven distribution

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to use for loop for a certain values for pc. Here I give an example,

```
pc=(0.02,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5)

for i in range (pc):
    phiCrit = i*np.max(phiPart_t)
    SigU = np.zeros(Nt)
    SigL = np.zeros(Nt)
    for k in range(0,Nt):
        toto = np.where(phiPart_t[:,k]>phiCrit)
        SigU[k] = Sig[np.max(toto)]
        SigL[k] = Sig[np.min(toto)]
    fitfuncU = lambda p, x: p[0] - (p[1]*np.log(x))
    errfuncU = lambda p, x, y: y - fitfuncU(p, x)
    time_fit=np.where(time>20)
    pfinal, success = optimize.leastsq(errfuncL, pinit[:], args=(time[time_fit], SigU[time_fit]))
    y=fitfuncU(pfinal,time)
    x=time[0:696]
    dx = x[1]-x[0]
    dydx = np.diff(y)/dx
    plt.figure(21)

    plot(x, dydx, label='time vs dfitfunc with various phi')
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('dSigU')
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlim(0,3500)
    plt.legend()
    savefig('21.png')
```

my aim is plot `time vs dydx` for several `phicrit` in a same figure. The error I got here it says `range() integer end argument expected, got tuple.` I also tried to make pc as list but it did not work. apart from different variables can someone explain me how can I run the whole process for different pc values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

`for i in pc`

`range(n)` returns an iterable containing the range `0, n`. It seems in this case the iterable you want is just `pc`.